# Probability and rates

Tags: probability

Suppose the probability of an accident every 5 minutes is $1$%. What's the probability of an accident every 10 minutes? Every 1 minute? Is it $2$% and $0.2$% respectively? That's what comes to mind intuitively. But when I try a weak attempt at math, even that doesn't make sense:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\textrm{accident} / 5 \textrm{min} &= \frac{1}{100} \\
2 \textrm{ accidents} / 10 \textrm{ mins}  &= \frac{1}{100} \\
1 \textrm{ accident} / 10 \textrm{ mins}  &= \frac{1}{200} = 0.5\text{%}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: You are correct, it doesn't make sense. If you set
$$
P(\text{there will be an accident in the next 5 minutes}) = 0.01
$$
Then
$$
P(\text{there will not be an accident in the next 5 minutes}) = 0.99
$$
and
$$
P(\text{there will not be an accident in the next 10 minutes}) = 0.99^2
$$
Can you continue from here?

Comment: This depends largely on how you choose to model things... For clarification, can more than one accident happen within a five-minute interval?  Or can only one or zero accidents happen within each five-minute interval?  If more than one can happen within a five-minute interval, is the probability of $1\%$ in reference to the probability of at least one accident happening then or the probability of exactly one accident happening then?  Should each five-minute window of time containing an accident be considered independent of each other five-minute window of time?

Comment: It may make more sense to model this as a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) rather than as a [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) as @MattiP. had.